# How to get the height of a div adjusted to the text when using margins...?

Tags: css, html, height

I tried to get the height of a div box adjusted to the text height by simply defining the min-height css property. However, this doesn't  work. The div  always seems to follow the margin definitions and does not adjust to the text hight. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" >
body {
margin:0;
}
.parallax-group {
position:relative;
height:100vh;
}
.sectiontext {
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
content: "";
margin-bottom:20%;
margin-top:15%;
margin-left:0px;
min-height: 1px;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section class = "parallax-group">
<div class = "sectiontext ">
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem solved: the "bottom:0;" style has to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: The "bottom:0" constraint has to be removed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" >
body {
margin:0;
}
.parallax-group {
position:relative;
height:100vh;
}
.sectiontext {
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
content: "";
margin-bottom:20%;
margin-top:15%;
margin-left:0px;
min-height: 1px;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section class = "parallax-group">
<div class = "sectiontext ">
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```